# Sending email via SMTP from an internal email address - mailbox unavailable or not local (.NET 4)

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient

My problem is that I can't send SMTP emails sent from a recipient hosted on my server. I have contact forms that work fine for emails with a from recipient as an external email address but now I require one of my systems to send emails from a domain hosted on the same server to any other provided email (subscriber) and it just gives me the error:

> Error Sending Email: Mailbox
>   unavailable. The server response was:
>   Requested action not taken: mailbox
>   unavailable or not local

I am running **mailEnable** on a **windows server** with **IIS7** and wondered if anyone was having this problem? I have tested the mailbox using the details above through outlook and it send / receives emails fine. Here is a code sample below showing what I'm using and as far as I know it should be authenticating fine. I also tried moving the config settings back into the C# code and had the same issue.

Example web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="test@test.com">
            <network defaultCredentials="true" host="mail.test.com" port="25" userName="test@test.com" password="******" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Example C# .NET 4 code:

```
try
{
 _emailMsg.Body = _MessageBody;
 _emailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

 SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();

 mSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

 mSmtpClient.Send(_emailMsg);
 return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 throw new Exception("Error Sending Email: " + ex.Message);

 return false;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the email recipient?

Comment: Sorry I setup the email object prior to this but it is set to the current logged in user and when I debug it shows that value exists.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code - are you sure that the recipient is on the same domain?

Comment: yes i've been testing with my domains and all email / websites etc is location on one server.

Comment: I did see another article saying it could be to do with the spam protection rules but I didnt think I had anything enabled and would of expected a different message

Comment: Is the SMTP Server the one in IIS? If so, have you configured it correctly for routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at MailEnable's website, there is some [guidance on the error messages](http://www.mailenable.com/kb/Content/Article.asp?ID=me020032) that might occur.

Guessing a bit further, it appears that your domain name exists on the web server and there is no issue there, but you have to ***explicitly white-list*** any email addresses in the `address-map.tab` file. There are more notes on the issue and their resolution in full is:

> The resolution here really resolves around when you think this error is being returned when it should not be.  If the address is thought to exist on the server then you need to check the SMTP logs activity for the transaction and then the debug to see if there are any error descriptions that better explain what happened when the address was sent to.  Then you should check your configuration to ensure that the address does exist.  It can also be a good idea to check the address-map.tab file in the MailEnable\Config directory or relevant database table for a line that contains the mailbox name in question.  If you are checking why the sender could not relay through the server then you should at this time check the client settings and ensure that the outbound settings in the client are configured as such so they can relay through the server to non local email addresses.

Comment: It was a combination of this and credentials being used (Default were being used and shouldn't of been)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
try {
    _emailMsg.Body = _MessageBody;
    _emailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

     SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient(server,25);
     mSmtpClient.Send(_emailMsg);
     return true;
} catch (Exception ex) { 
     throw new Exception("Error Sending Email: " + ex.Message);
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.